# Installed library cannot be found by CMake

Tags: cmake, directfb

I have the following problem when running CMake.

```
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
DIRECTFB_INCLUDE_DIR (ADVANCED)
  used as include directory in directory /u/menie482/workspace/AtariTEXPLORE
  used as include directory in directory /u/menie482/workspace/AtariTEXPLORE/rl_common
  used as include directory in directory /u/menie482/workspace/AtariTEXPLORE/rl_agent
  used as include directory in directory /u/menie482/workspace/AtariTEXPLORE/rl_env
DIRECTFB_LIBRARY (ADVANCED)
  linked by target "experiment" in directory /u/menie482/workspace/AtariTEXPLORE
```

Actually, I have checked that the DirectFB is already installed when running

```
locate libdirectfb
```

So, what shall I do to let CMake know where DIrectFB is? An inconvenient constraint is that I cannot do sudo on this machine..

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you are trying to use something like find_package(directfb) in your CMakeLists.txt file.  That can only run if you have `/usr/share/cmake/Modules/directfb.cmake` (Ubuntu 12.04).

My second guess is you are using something like pkg_module(directfb) in your CMakeLists.txt file.  That can only run if you have directfb.pc somewhere.

Otherwise
Where are you setting the variables DIRECTFB_INCLUDE_DIR and DIRECTFB_LIBRARY.

As an alternate step, try using [`find_library()`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake2.6docs.html#command%3afind_library). You will have to give exact path of libdirectfb.so and do something like

> find_library(DIRECT_FB  NAMES directfb PATHS path/directfb.so )
>     target_link_libraries( MyLibraryOrMyExecutable ${DIRECT_FB} )